# Adding dependency on a non-compiled file in a Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I have the following code generation scheme:

- The original file is *.c.macro
- It is processed by a special program that generates the *.c file. The program uses external XML files mentioned in the original .c.macro file. Somthing along this line:

  macroprocess foo.c.macro -o foo.c
- Then the *.c file is compiled to *.o normally

What I want to do is to make the .c file dependant on the XML files. So that if the XML changes, macroprocessing is automatically redone when 'make' command is invoked.
I can modify the code of the macroprocessor so that it would generate a list of all XMLs and write it somewhere, but I have no idea how to incorporate it into a makefile. Apparently I would need to play with 'include' command in the makefile, but usually it's employed to add dependencies on actual code like .h files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get your macroprocess to write a dependency file (e.g. *.xmldep) for each *.c.macro file you can do:

```
-include $(C_MACRO:.c.macro=.xmldep)
```

where $(C_MACRO) is a variable that contains your *.c.macro files.

The `-` in front will ensure that the first time, the make will not fail when it cannot locate the dependency files.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `foo.xml` as a dependency of `foo.c` and use a [`filter`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions) command to get only the `%.c.macro` file as arguments for `macroprocess`.

Something like this:

```
# Basic targets
all: foo

foo: foo.o
    gcc -o $@ $^

foo.o: foo.c
    gcc -o $@ -c $<

# Special target with filter
foo.c: foo.c.macro
    macroprocess -o $@ $(filter %.c.macro,@^)

# Adding foo.xml as a dependency of foo.c
foo.c: foo.xml

.PHONY: all foo
```